# difference in string initilialization

Tags: c, arrays, string

Is there any difference between the following string initializations:

```
char *string = "Hello";
```

vs

```
char string[] = "Hello";
```

I've seen both initializations in examples. Thanks!

Comment: There is no newline in the string literal `"Hello"`.

Comment: The "terminating character of a string" is not a newline.

Comment: String terminate with `'\0'` not `'\n'`

Comment: That individual coded something else than this. I bet he mentions `fgets` and its associated little 'problem' somewhere in that video.

Comment: I bet you had a very strange result from the `printf`! *Always* check the return values - here it was `NULL`.

Comment: I realize my stupidity, I apologize. however, are the two above equivalent? thanks again

Comment: I'd be surprised if you saw this initialization in working code. It's missing a closing `"`.

Comment: You cant modify any character in the first example,but whereas you can modify in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have now changed the question. Here are two differences: in the first case

```
char *string = "Hello";
```

the string is a "literal" and cannot be modified. The variable `string` is a pointer, and has a memory requirement of 4 or 8 bytes depending on whether you are working with 32-bit or 64-bit.

In the second case

```
char string[] = "Hello";
```

the text is copied to the array `string` which uses 6 bytes of memory (subject to alignment) - length of "Hello" and a string terminator. You can modify this array.

A comment on your original question: It is very boring checking the result of every function you think should be working properly, and providing a recovery strategy (or at least a sharp `exit` with a reason) because it gets you no further towards your goal. It doubles the development work, but newbies fail to realise it halves or quarters the debugging pain (and used as a coding principle makes for robust code).

Answer (score 0):

`char string[]` creates a char array on stack or in the segment of the memory where global variables are stored. `char *string` creates a char pointer that points at an array in the segment of memory where compile-time cinstants are stored. In C++ it would be read-only memory, not sure about C.

Answer (score 0):

char string[] = "Hello";:

1) generates an array containing the actual characters 'Hello\0' with the supplied name, exactly where the definition is located

2) The resulting array can be modified by the executing code.

char *string = "Hello";:

1) generates an array containing the actual characters 'Hello\0' in readonly memory and places a pointer to that string with the supplied name, exactly where the definition is located.

2) The resulting array can NOT be modified by the executing code; but the pointer could be modified to point elsewhere.